# Echoing HTML correctly from PHP

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a class with a method called `paint()` so i call `$object->paint();` and it returns the html code to display the object the way i like it.
In a function, i have an array of those objects, so i do something like this:

```
$code = '<p class="wrapper">';
foreach( $object_arr as $object ){
    $code .= $object->paint();
}
$code .='</p>';
echo $code;
```

but the result iḿ getting is this:

```
<p class="wrapper"></p>
<figure id="f1">Figure 1</figure>
<figure id="f2">Figure 2</figure>
...
<figure id="fn">Figure n</figure>
```

The function paint() returns the code to paint the object, i was expecting to see:

```
<p class="wrapper">
    <figure id="f1">Figure 1</figure>
    <figure id="f2">Figure 2</figure>
    ...
    <figure id="fn">Figure n</figure>
</p>
```

What am i doing it wrong?

Comment: not showing us the paint() function for one

Comment: The result you're looking at might be corrected by your browser. `p` does not accept `figure` as a child, so the browser might correct it by closing your first `<p class="wrapper">`

Comment: That is probably the reason, can you put that as an answer so i can vote it as the correct one? Thank You.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say that your object's `paint()` method isn't buffering as you expect. What happens if you add `ob_flush()` to the last line inside your `foreach()` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're looking at might be corrected by your browser. `p` does not accept `figure` as a child, so the browser might correct it by closing your first `<p class="wrapper">`.

Comment: Thanks, that was correct. It actually works if I use <section> instead of <p>

Comment: Note that the real code echoed by PHP was what you expected to see. With Firebug (for instance), you can see the real code sent from the server, before any manipulation from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Some more code would be helpful, but this might put you on the right track.

What is $object_arr an array of. Can you post the example of the object in the object array?

With my example you would have to pass in the index as well to get the id="fnn".

If you post some more code I can clarify my answer.

```
<?php
function paint($str){
    return '<figure id="fn">'.$str.'</figure>';
}
$object_arr =Array('happy','beans');
$code = '<p class="wrapper">';
foreach( $object_arr as $object ){
    $code .= paint($object);
}
$code .='</p>';
echo $code;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're using single quotes, then put a tab before the method call:

```
$code .= '    ' . $object->paint();
```

But this would be easier:

```
$code .= "\t" . $object->paint();
```

Comment: The indentation is not the issue here, but the order of the output.

Comment: There are at least a few reasons to not do this. Aside being totally pointless, it also adds minuscule processing overhead and added data to the files.